# Using Find to Substring in formula field

Tags: formula, formula-field

I'm trying to substring the following sentence which sits on another field called `Item_Accounting_Class__c`

`1111111100-Testing(ESS)`

I need to pull the `ESS` out of it, which will always be encaplsed by (), Any ideas?  I tried to use Find, and Right but I am unable to get the results I require

Comment: so you are trying to find the value of an arbitrary string enclosed by parens somewhere in the string?  And there is only at most one set of parens and they are guaranteed to be matching?  E.g  `abcxxx (thisiswhatiwant)xxxx` - and you want to return `thisiswhatiwant` ?. The best way to resolve tricky formulas is to make the formula simple - debug it, then add more, debug it, etc. You can debug by exposing the formula field on the page layout

Comment: I'm trying to put this in a formula field

Comment: yes, I got that -- but in order to answer the question, the scope needs to be clarified as suggested by my first 2 questions in the above comment. I also suggested some self-help technique that will let you experiment with FIND and MID